# jquery ajax loading overlay plugin

Tags: jquery

Does anybody know of a nice plugin for ajax loading overlay preventing any other action in the browser till the data gets loaded.

Comment: FYI that's called a 'modal' dialog or popup - good to know if you're script hunting :)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

[loadmask plugin](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-loadmask/)

Comment: looks simple & light weight... have not yet tried to see if it has a problem...

Comment: if you use tab, you can still edit in the blocked fields.

Comment: @Popo: apply the mask to BODY element. That way whole page is blocked.

Answer (score 27):

Try blockUI: http://malsup.com/jquery/block/

This doesn't have any connection to AJAX inherently, but it's something you can invoke when doing your own AJAX calls separately.

Answer (score 6):

i made one more tailored to this sort of thing:

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/loading

All you need to do is:

```
$.loading({onAjax:true,mask:true});
```

That'll wire it up to ajax events automatically.  There are a great many more options and features though.  You can use text, arbitrary elements, apply "pulse" effects and more. Check out the demo:

http://jquery-values.googlecode.com/svn/other/loading/jquery.loading.htm

Comment: great plugin, any ideas why it wouldnt work with jQtouch? http://code.google.com/p/jqtouch/

Comment: no, and sadly i have no iPhone to try it on.  what kind of problem are you seeing?

Comment: It is, however, hardly standalone and is dependant on alot of other plugins.

Comment: This is great, but for some reason it only shows the first time I click the button. on subsequent tries it masks the div but does not display the overlay. anyone know why?

Comment: Sadly, it's been neglected.  I need to upgrade it for moderm jquery, probably move to github too.

Answer (score 3):

This is the best: http://malsup.com/jquery/block/#overview

Answer (score -1):

You could use `dojox.widget.Standby`, but it requires you to mark the content for the overlay with `data-dojo-type="dojox.widget.Standby"`

Then you only need to get the widget with: `dijit.byId('id').hide()/show()`

See: [dojox.widget.Standby documentation](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dojox/widget/Standby.html)

Comment: This question is tagged [tag:jquery]. I don't think the OP wants to use dojo.