# Loading Indicator w/o Ajax

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, load

My ASP.net webpage has a couple of javascript functions which only work when Ajax is disabled. But I need to have a wait screen/loading indicator, because the waittime can be over a minute. Can anyone help me to get a javascript/jquery or something else non Ajax that I can use a loading indicator in ASP.net?

Example:

[image: Example]

Comment: I take it that loading bar in your post doesn't cut it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could:

```
var loading = document.createElement('img');
loading.src = "loading-animation.gif";
document.body.appendChild(loading);
```

Comment: Thank you for your replay, how can I implement this in my asp.net code?

Comment: By wrapping it in a script element

Comment: Can you maybe give me an example that it fires when the loading begins and stopts when the loading is done?

Comment: No, since I have no idea how to tell when your unspecified thing that isn't Ajax starts or stops.

Answer (score 1):

That's easy:

- create a load image here: http://ajaxload.info/
- show it when your JavaScript starts
- hide it when finished

If you want to block user interaction, take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1262377/jquery-ajax-loading-overlay-plugin).

Answer (score -1):

You can try with these plugins:

http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/sonic-looping-loaders/

http://heartcode.robertpataki.com/canvasloader/

And this one has more kind of loaders http://preloaders.net/